# yii работа с формами через ajax

Tags: yii

Здравствуйте, облазил уже весь интернет, но так и не смог найти решение.
Только начинаю знакомство и yii и не могу разобраться, как реализовать форму через ajax по средствам yii.
Знаю как сделать без помощи yii

```
$.getJSON("fil.php", {},function(data){});
```

В fil.php мы обрабатываем и ответ отправляем в функцию.
А как сделать все тоже самое, но средствами yii?
В сети много форм, например

```
<?php        
        $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'ID ВАШЕЙ ФОРМЫ',
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
            ));
    ?>

    <!-- здесь ваш html-код формы -->

    <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Send my coupon', '', array(
            'type' => 'POST',
            'success' => 'js: function(data) {
                }',
        ),
        array(
            'type' => 'submit',
    ); ?>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Где мы тут обрабатываем данные?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные обрабатываются в контроллере, форма только отправляет их. Посмотреть пример реализации отправки формы через ajax можно [тут](https://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/69969-yii2-ajax-submit/page__view__findpost__p__296693)